# Alternative to Global Variables For Android

Tags: android, global-variables

If the webservice calls in my app are of the form:

```
[domain]/USER_ID/[action]
```

what is the best way to keep track of the user id? Doing something like this:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private String userId;
    public String getUserId() { return this.userId; }
}
```

seems the fastest, but I am reluctant to start down the slippery slope that is global variables. I have seen some people recommend using SharedPreferences for things like this, but I don't know if that is a good solution either considering that I will need to access the data pretty frequently during normal use of the app. Doing this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences(...);
String userId = sp.getString(...);
```

every single time I need the information seems like it would cause quite a bit of overhead. Are there any alternatives to use in this type of scenario? What is the best way to deal with keeping track of global variables in Android without using global variables? (alternatively, are global variables maybe worth using in Android?)

Comment: This approach gets messy is when you store *state* about your application in global vars. When you cannot determine how a particular method will behave without knowing the state of something external to the method. Storing a piece of data which you need access to frequently makes sense as Patrick has said. If you need to persist the value between instances of your app, then save it to shared preferences when it's created/changed and retrieve it in onCreate() of the Application then access it as you have shown. Some will argue userId is state but that's pendantry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending the Application class as you described is the most common method of storing and using global variable. This is a perfect fit for small amounts of data you need to access frequently across the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

using contexts, see this tutorial:

http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136